# Na herança com os atributos privados, a classe filha não toma os seus atributos da classe mãe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, encapsulamento

O [artigo da devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/encapsulamento-polimorfismo-heranca-em-java/12991) diz que o modificador `private` não dá acesso aos seus atributos nas suas classes filhas. Tem uma tabela com os modificadores.

Na herança com os atributos privados, a classe filha não toma os seus atributos da classe mãe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Membros privados sempre estão restritos à classe em que foram declaradas. Mesmo quando há herança, eles não são acessíveis à classe filha. Esta classe até recebe os membros privados de sua mãe, mas não consegue acessá-los no código da classe filha, nem consegue acessar os membros da mãe através de `super`. Quando opta-se por um membro privado está dizendo que ele não pode vazar "em hipótese alguma" da sua classe, nem mesmo as derivadas.

Não é tão em hipótese alguma assim, é possível fazer via reflexão, mas é um truque para passar por cima da linguagem. Isso pode ser abusado, por isso propositalmente não é fácil fazer. É preciso entender que a proteção que a linguagem dá é só para cobrir o uso indevido bem intencionado. Não é uma garantia que nunca haverá acesso aos membros.

Membros que devem ser acessados por classes filhas devem ser declarados como `protected`. Aí há herança destes membros com visibilidade nela, assim como o `public`, obviamente. Acho que fica óbvio também que os protegidos não podem ser acessados fora da classe filha.

Outro erro comum é achar que a classe filha acessa os membros de outra classe quando há herança, isto não é o caso. Os membros da classe mãe passam fazer parte da classe filha, não está acessando em outro lugar. Não há dois objetos distintos, uma para a instância mãe e outra para a instância filha, só haverá a instância filha que possui todos os membros, seus próprios e da mãe.

Bem a grosso modo é como se o compilador copiasse tudo da classe mãe e colasse na classe filha. Você não está vendo os membros ali no seu código, mas eles estão lá quando colocou que é para herdar de uma classe. Os membros privados são copiados, mas não são visíveis ao código da classe filha.

Os métodos *acessores* geralmente são públicos e são herdados. Se não quer que eles sejam públicos mas quer que a classe filha tenha acesso a eles, então eles devem ser `protected`, não tem outra forma. E claro que a variável que vai suportar esses métodos devem ter no mínimo a mesma visibilidade - eu diria no máximo a mesma também, até pode não ser assim, mas não faz o menor sentido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tive essa dúvida porque muitas vezes é colocada como valores padrões para os atributos com a inicialização nos construtores. Pensei que se eu faço herança de uma classe que tem essas inicializações no construtor e eu dando super na classe filha não poderia pegar aqueles valores inicializados da classe mãe?

Comment: Então, se eles forem `public` ou `protected`, eles estarão na classe filha e poderá acessá-los assim. Se eles eles forem `private`, não tem como acessá-los diretamente pela classe filha, pode através de um método `super`, que não seja privado que faça isto por você. Não tenho certeza se entendi essa dúvida. Quando é assim tente colocar um na pergunta um exemplo concreto do que está tentando fazer, assim fica mais fácil visualizar e propor uma alternativa.

Comment: OMG! Agora entendi o construtor é public.

Comment: Em geral, sim, é possível fazer ele privado, mas em poucos casos isto é útil.

Answer (score 5):

Atributos privados ficam somente acessíveis na classe que os implementa. Classes filhas não tem acesso. Caso queira um atributo sem visibilidade pública, mas que as classes filhas possam acessar, use a propriedade `protected`

Edit: Não tenho permissão pra comentar então vou por um adendo a respeito do uso do `super`. Ele permite acessar a implementação de um método da classe pai. Não consegue interagir com atributos.
Exemplo:

```
public class ABC{
  public DEF()
  //implementação imaginária aqui
}
public class ABC2 extends ABC{
  @Override //não é necessário
  public DEF(){
    super(); //invoca a implementação da classe pai deste método.
             //Só pode ser usado na primeira linha do método caso não
             //queira dar uma sobrecarga/overload do método
             //Se o método fosse privado isso não seria possível
}
```

Comment: Mas no construtor da classe pai se tiver atributos já inicializados posso dar super na classe filha para pegar a inicialização dos atributos, não?

Comment: Não deveria ser?     public ABCD2(){
        super();
     }

Comment: Não, super só serve pra invocar a implementação da classe pai de um método. Você nao pode usar super pra invocar a estrutura da classe pai. O que é privado, não ficará visível. Todo o resto, protected e public, é visível.

Comment: Só programando para eu ver isso. Vou fazer esse teste simples.

Comment: Entenda que super só invoca, não te dá acesso. Se atributos privados estão sendo alterados num método que você possa chamar o super, os valores vão ser realmente alterados, mas nem por isso ele vai te dar acesso direto ao atributo.

Comment: Ok. Obrigada. :)

Answer (score 2):

Quando uma variável ou método está marcada como **private**. Somente a classe que implementou diretamente terá acesso. Nem classes filhas podem acessar campos privados.

Se você quiser isso, use **protected**. É privado para outras classes, mas classes filhas podem acessar.

Comment: Mas e quanto a questao de herança? eu não posso herdar os atributos e ter acesso a eles utilizando o super?

Comment: As classes do mesmo pacote podem acessar os atributos protecteds mesmo sem serem herdeiras, não?

Comment: Podem, uma classe no mesmo pacote pode instanciar/pegar uma instancia da outra classe do mesmo pacote e ler os atributos protegidos dela

Comment: ops. Realmente, confundi com o default

Answer (score 1):

A classe filha toma os atributos da classe mãe: sim e não.

#### Sim

Eles existem na classe filha, só não podem ser acessados por ela, para resolver isso você pode:

- colocar o modificador de acesso da variável/método como **protected** ou **public**
- criar um método `get` ou `set` como `getNome` **public** ou **protected**, por exemplo para poder pegar ou setar o valor na variável da classe mãe
- Usando **reflection**, existe um recurso que você "ignora" todos paradigmas de acesso do java e simplesmente acessa/altera os dados de qualquer objeto

#### Não

Se você não utilizar nenhum dos artifícios anteriores realmente é impossível

## Editado

Existem várias formas de implementar o que eu disse  então vai só um exemplo

#### Exemplo de como setar nas variáveis private da classe mãe

```
public class Mae {

      private String nome;

      protected String getNome() {
          return this.nome;
      }

      protected void setNome(final String nome) {
          this.nome = nome;
      }
}

public class Filha extends Mae {

      public void main(String args[]){
          new Filha().setNome("hahahahha setei o nome na minha mãe");
      }
}
```