# Classes que implementam interfaces são consideradas subclasses?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Tenho uma interface `Veiculo`, uma classe `Peugeot` que implementa `Veiculo`. Esse `Peugeot` é considerado subclasse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Conceitos

Vamos conceituar as coisas. Embora nem todo mundo concorde com essas definições, vou colocar um entendimento que muitos têm.

#### [Subclasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses)

É a capacidade de [**reusar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55493/101) código de algo existente.

É algo interno para a classe.

É ela mesma "copiando" seletivamente o que existe na classe base. Ela pega os campos e os métodos que existem na classe e os toma como se fossem seus.

Normalmente se dá por [herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101). Isto é, uma classe deriva de outra classe.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, até mesmo as [partes privadas de uma classe são herdadas pela classe que a herda, apenas a visibilidade fica limitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108574/101).

#### [Subtipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)

É a capacidade de um tipo se passar por outro, de alguma forma o [**substituindo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) em determinadas situações como se fosse o próprio tipo esperado.

É algo externo de quem consome o tipo.

Um método espera um objeto de um tipo, mas ele pode receber um objeto de outro tipo que atenda os requisitos do tipo originalmente aceito.

Normalmente se dá pelo [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101). Pode ser de uma classe concreta, uma [classe abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101), uma [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) ou um *trait* ([em Java 8 é possível algo parecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101)), entre outras possibilidades em algumas linguagens.

Note que por ser algo de uso externo tudo que se refere ao subtipo deve ser obrigatoriamente público.

As classes costumam ter o [subtipo estrutural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) e o [subtipo comportamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A interface, pura,  é apenas um contrato, é sobre tipagem e não sobre implementação, não tem nem estado, nem comportamento.

Java só trabalha com [subtipo nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).

#### Herança

É comum quando tratamos de herança de estarmos falando das duas coisas, apesar de serem conceitos separados. Tem linguagem que faz subclasse sem subtipo (não Java). Algumas possuem conceitos totalmente distintos, mas não vou entrar em detalhes, não é o foco da pergunta.

Por isso alguns dizem que [Java não permite múltipla herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101) e [outros dizem que sim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89273/101). Depende da definição. Java permite simples subclasse e múltiplos subtipos.

## A implementação de interface é uma subclasse?

Em parte a pergunta, não muito clara mas respondível, já está respondida. Interfaces tem mais a ver com subtipo e não com subclasse. Mas em Java 8 é possível ter interfaces que se comportam como subclasses. Mas apenas quando se usa os métodos *default*, mas vamos deixar isso de lado para facilitar.

Então:

```
public interface MeioTransporte { ... }
public interface Veiculo extends MeioTransporte { ... } //subtipo
public class Carro implements Veiculo { ... } //sutipo
public class Peugeot extends Carro { ... } //subclasse e subtipo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Inheritance.java).

Os exemplos não são bons, mas segui a pergunta. `Veiculo` dificilmente seria uma interface.

Classes que implementam interfaces estão apenas fazendo subtipo, portanto as [interfaces são supertipos de classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87488/101) ou de outras interfaces.

## Conclusão

Vou reforçar que é [difícil fazer subclasse e subtipo certo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101). A maioria dos programadores não tem a menor noção de como fazer certo, muitos sequer sabem o que significa OOP. Mesmo programadores experientes têm dificuldade de fazer certo em vários casos. Então muito cuidado para manipular essa "arma".

Comment: Perfeito!!!!!!!

Comment: Vai me ajudar em uma apresentação que farei hj.