# Erro ao adicionar objetos lado a lado em um array

Tags: java, arraylist

Preciso adicionar os métodos *get* para uma `ArrayList`, tentei com vírgulas para separar, porém não funciona, só consigo adicionar se for um embaixo do outro, o que não serve pra mim. Tentei criar a `ArrayList` do tipo da classe que quero puxar, porém ele chama os construtores, o que também não serviria.

O erro é:

> (actual and formal arguments lists differ in length)

Junto com isso acima lista todos os meios de adicionar itens na lista com o mesmo erro.

A `ArrayList` precisa armazenar os objetos da classe `CaixaLapis` que basicamente são *gets e sets*.

```
package prj_interdisciplinar;

//importar listas no Java
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Pedido implements Manipulacao{
    private Data data = new Data(1, 1, 2001);
    private Cliente cliente = new Cliente("semnome", "semcpf", "semtel");
    private float totalpedido;
    private ArrayList cxlapis = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList papel = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList caderno = new ArrayList();

    //construtor sem parametros
    public Pedido(){

    }

    //Teste com ArrayList fora do método cadastro
    public void adicionaCaixaLapis(){
        CaixaLapis cxl = new CaixaLapis();
        cxlapis.add(cxl.getQuantidade(), cxl.isColorido(), cxl.getMarca(), cxl.getValor());
    }

    void imprimeLista() {
        for(int i = 0; i<cxlapis.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(cxlapis.get(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the totalpedido
     */
    public float getTotalpedido() {
        return totalpedido;
    }

    /**
     * @param totalpedido the totalpedido to set
     */
    public void setTotalpedido(float totalpedido) {
        this.totalpedido = totalpedido;
    }

    //calcular pedido
    public void calculaTotalPedido(){
        totalpedido = 0;
    }

    //chamada manipulacao
    @Override
    public boolean cadastro(){
        imprimeLista();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String consulta(){

        return  "texto";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)), não seria [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: Tentei com o addAll, porém o erro informa que nenhum dos métodos de adicionar dá certo pois se diferenciam no tamanho, algo do tipo, vou tentar jogar o erro ali no post.

Comment: No caso, aquelas funções retornam valores diferentes? Isto é, `getQuantidade()`, `isColorido()`, `getMarca()` e `getValor()` retornam valores de tipos diferentes?

Comment: int, boolean, String e float são os valores, a ideia seria armazenar lado a lado para imprimir a linha com informações ou pelo menos exibí-los lado a lado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é que o método [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) só aceita um argumento e você está tentando usar vários. Este é o erro, então se usar um funcionará. Eu sei que não é o que deseja, mas é o que dá para responder. Provavelmente quer fazer outra coisa aí, talabvez criar um objeto e colocar nesse *array*.

Me desculpe se não é o que deseja ver, mas é o melhor que posso fazer. Resolver este problema não serve para muita coisa. A quantidade de erros neste código é enorme e está aprendendo muita coisa errada, então é até melhor que não funcione.

Não consigo listar todos os erros e alguns só posso especular por não conhecer os requisitos, mas dá para inferir algo pelo que universalmente se faz.

Essa herança não parece fazer sentido, um `Pedido` não é uma `Manipulacao` seja lá o que isto signifique. Se não entende para que serve herança não tente fazer.

Esses *arrays* nesta classe não parecem fazer sentido ainda mais sem usar a sintaxe genérica. Nenhum pedido real teria essas coisas fixas, é uma modelagem errada, por isso eu digo para nem se preocupar com o erro apresentado, ele só existe porque a classe já está conceitualmente errada e consertando esses erros o erro da pergunta deixará de existir. O mesmo vale para a criação do cliente.

Esta classe que cria data certamente é um erro, já dá para perceber pela forma como o construtor foi feito, prefira usar o que tem pronto.

`float` não pode ser usada para dinheiro. Não faz sentido criar um construtor vazio que não faça nada, os nomes dos identificadores estão ruins, os métodos não parecem fazer o que seus nomes indicam.

Comment: É sobre um trabalho da faculdade, como estou aprendendo não imaginei que tivesse tantas coisas sem sentido, porém o jeito como foi proposto o trabalho foi realmente horrível. Obrigado pela ajuda, já sei também que não posso me basear neste código para fazer nada hahaha

Comment: implementar uma interface pode ser chamado de herança ?

Comment: @Gustavo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101