# Os atributos de uma superclasse são considerados também atributos da subclasse?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, atributos, documentação

Para explicar melhor, criei o exemplo abaixo:

#### Diagrama UML:

[image: UML]

#### Classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {
  private String nome;
  private int idade;
  private String endereco;

  //construtor, getters e setters
}
```

#### Classe Funcionario:

```
public class Funcionario extends Pessoa {
  private String cargo;

  //construtor, getters e setters
}
```

A classe `Funcionario` é subclasse de `Pessoa`, herdando os atributos `nome`, `idade` e `endereco`. Esses atributos estão declarados na classe `Pessoa`, porém também podem ser acessados pela classe
`Funcionario`.

Na documentação do código, é correto considerar os atributos da superclasse como atributos da subclasse?

Por exemplo, eu posso declarar que os atributos de `Funcionario` são `nome`, `idade`, `endereco` e `cargo`?

Mesmo parte deles sendo declarados na superclasse?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Na herança com os atributos privados, a classe filha não toma os seus atributos da classe mãe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108574/na-heran%c3%a7a-com-os-atributos-privados-a-classe-filha-n%c3%a3o-toma-os-seus-atributos)

Comment: *"Na documentação do código, é correto considerar os atributos da superclasse como atributos da subclasse?"* sim pode considerar... o fato de usar herança ou não é um mero fato de implementação de código...poderia usar uma linguagem não orientada a objeto e ter de duplicar a classe, a documentação deve abstrair isso, ou seja, importa saber se "Funcionario" tem "idade", já como isso é implementado é responsabilidade do código :) Note que, quando digo documentação é algo externo ao código

Comment: Obrigado pela recomendação da pergunta Cmte Cardeal, o conteúdo pode me ajudar futuramente, mas o comentário do Ricardo foi muito esclarecedor para minha dúvida. Agradeço pela ajuda. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentar é convenção, as regras são adotadas de acordo com o jeito que a pessoa/equipe determina que deva ser. Algumas ferramentas que ajudam documentar só trabalham de uma determinada forma. Então pode fazer de um jeito ou de outro, só deve ser consistente e sempre fazer igual.

Nas documentações públicas é comum escolher entre:

- não documentar o que veio herdado
- documentar só o que foi sobreposto, o que não acontece em campos
- documentar tudo que está disponível na classe

Tudo isso para membros públicos. O que eu nunca vi é documentar os membros privados de uma classe, porque o que é privado é detalhe de implementação, portanto não deve ser documentado para as pessoas usarem. O que é documentação gera um contrato, e se escolheu algo privado é porque quer liberdade para mudar no futuro, portanto não pode gerar um contrato para as pessoas usarem.

O exemplo citado é de campos privados, portanto não deve estar na documentação de ambas as classes. Se é privado sequer você tem acesso direto na subclasse, ao contrário do que afirma a pergunta.

Note que [estou usando o termo campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) porque provavelmente vai documentar um código feito em alguma linguagem de programação, atributo só é usado em UML, que é algo que não tem utilidade prática. E de certa forma é uma documentação, que fica defasada facilmente e/ou gera dois trabalhos. E ela escolheu que não terá acesso aos "atributos" de outra classe, pelo menos não privativamente, como pode ser visto na pergunta.

Não entrei na questão de erros de *design* porque isso não é o foco da pergunta.